# JAVA - How to detect the first zero in validation

Tags: java, validation

For this code I need to detect postcodes with 4 integers, the code I have has this however if I input a number such as '0432' the number '0' isn't detected. If anyone can help it would be appreciated :)

```
    while (count == 1)
    {
        System.out.print("Input a postcode for us to send you the package: ");
        try
        {
            postage = in.nextInt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("This is an invalid input!");
            in.next();
            continue;
        }
        String valid = Integer.toString(postage);
        if (valid.length() > 4)
        {
            System.out.println("This is not a correct postcode!");
            continue;
        }
        if (valid.length() < 4)
        {
            System.out.println("This is not a correct postcode!");
            continue;
        } 
        if (valid.length() == 4)
        {
            continue;
        }

        else if (postage >= 0000 && postage <= 0999)
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Read it (and store it) as a `String`. And us post-codes are 5 or 9 digits. Not 4.

Comment: From Australia, use 4 here

Comment: Yeah.. roughly 20% of nations use a [four digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes) postal code. Anyhow, `Integer.toString(int)` is the way to go (or do what Elliot suggests and just take the data as String in the first place). Then you can parse your string character by character with String.charAt() to find zeroes.